# Lenna compression save all black python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I have this code that compresses lena.tif image to black and white using the fourth bit of high significance. My problem occurs when when I save the image, the final result is all black and I don't know why.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_img = Image.open("lenac.tif")
x_gray = x_img.convert("L")
x = np.array(x_gray)
for i in range(0,4):
    y = x > (2**(7-i))-1
    z = x - y * (2**(7-i))
    x = z    

new_img = Image.fromarray(y.astype('uint8'),'L')
plt.imshow(new_img, cmap='gray')
new_img.save("lena_4 .bmp")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y` is a boolean array.  So when you convert it to `uint8` your values are all either 0 or 1.

But when you're create an `Image` from `y`, you specify mode `'L'`, which is [8 bits per pixel](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

So you can simply scale the pixels to 8-bit range:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_img = Image.open("lenac.tif")
x_gray = x_img.convert("L")
x = np.array(x_gray)
for i in range(0,4):
    y = x > (2**(7-i))-1
    z = x - y * (2**(7-i))
    x = z

y = y.astype('uint8') * 255        # This scales the pixel values

new_img = Image.fromarray(y ,'L')  # Use y here instead of y.astype(...)
plt.imshow(new_img, cmap='gray')
#plt.show()
new_img.save("lena_4.bmp")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The final image is not all black. It is simply very dark because all pixels are 0 (black) or 1 (almost black). After all,`y` is either 0 or 1 (False or True). `imshow` scales the range so that you see something not as black as it really is. Are you sure it is `y` that needs to be converted to an image?

By the way, `z` is unnecessary. Write line  in the loop as `x = x - y * (2**(7-i))`